# How can I make countdown time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

So I have my code here:

```
import time
from random import uniform
rng = uniform(1, 3)
start = time.time()
while True:
    if time.time() == start + rng:
        print("finally")
```

My question is: how can I make the program print "finally"?

Comment: Try `if time.time() >= start + rng:` instead.

Comment: thanks! it works now :D

Comment: 'if time.time() >= start + rng:' i think you should have an infinite loop, even with that suggestion you should print infinite "finally"

Comment: also add a break statement inside if body. otherwise it will result in infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

add a break also ;)

```
import time
from random import uniform
rng = uniform(1, 3)
start = time.time()
while True:
    if time.time() >= start + rng:    # first edit here (also as suggested by Patrick Haugh)
        print("finally")
        break                         # add this also to skip infinite looping
```